# If clause multiple condition jsp

Tags: jsp, session, if-statement

I have problem with if clause for the multiple condition

here is code

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("type")=="admin"){ %>
```

and this is for set attribute for session

```
if (resultset.next()) {
    String type = resultset.getString("type");
    session.setAttribute("userid",n);
    session.setAttribute("type", type);
    response.sendRedirect("company.jsp");
} else {
    out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
}
```

It doesn't work. How fix it?

Comment: Can you explain it more?Is the if clause in company.jsp?What you want to done with if clause?can you explain it

Comment: sorry the if clause is in company.jsp

Comment: what you want to check with the if clause?

Comment: this is login system when userid not null and level(type) == admin can go to company.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.session.getattribute() return a String value.So use .equals()

```
 <% if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("type").equals("admin")){ %>
 /*do some operations*/
 <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("type")=="admin"){ %>
```

The second comparison is wrong , `getAttribute()` returns an `Object` not `String`.Cast it to `String` to make the comparison .Also never use `==` for `String` comparisons, instead use `eqauls()`.